# simple jQuery to the color of the word to blue one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My simple source is

```
$lol = $(".lol");

$lol.each( function(index) {    $(this).delay(200*index).css("color", "blue");  }   );
```

The Fiddle is here

http://jsfiddle.net/ra53Lzhw/

I am trying to make each of the word to change its colour to blue one at a time.  How can I do that?

And how can I do that, so it changes gradually, instead of suddenly changing to blue?  Thanks a lot, Stack Overflow!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
$lol = $(".lol");

$lol.each( function(index) {    
  $(this).delay(200 * index).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).css("color", "blue");
    next();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=lol> Div One </div>
<div class=lol> Div Two </div>
<div class=lol> Div Three </div>
<div class=lol> Div Four </div>
```

Comment: +1 Very nice use of the ability to manually insert callbacks into the fx queue (which is the only way that delay works).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LftjjnL0/4/).

Basically you use `setInterval` and jQuery selectors to color the text lines ine by one.

```
var hnd = setInterval ( function () {
    $(".lol:not(.blu):first")
        .addClass("blu")
    ;
}, 2000);

setTimeout ( function () { clearInterval(hnd);                
$(".lol").removeClass("blu"); }, 10000 );
```

The css clause:

```
.blu { color: blue; }
```